# Querying The Database for Join Tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Alright, I've got a query here. (Using Oracle SQL Developer)

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, COLUMN_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ID1' OR COLUMN_NAME = 'ID2';
```

This gets me every table in my database that has a column `ID1` or a column `ID2`.  Let's say I've got a number of join tables, with `ID1` and `ID2` joined in a specific table, but `ID1` and `ID2` are in a lot of separate tables as well.

How would I set up this query to select distinct `TABLE_NAME`s that have both `COLUMN_NAME`s in it?  IE, querying `ID1` and `ID2` returns a `JOIN_TABLE1`, but `ID1` and `ID3` returns only `JOIN_TABLE2`, I don't get shared tables that have ONLY one or the other.

Comment: I suppose `, COLUMN_NAME` is a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use intersect

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ID1'
INTERSECT 

SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, COLUMN_NAME 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ID2';
```

Comment: A good, straight-forward solution. There is one semicolon too many, however.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   semicolon removed ... (copy and paste too fast) ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to aggregate your rows and count, so you access the table just once:

```
select owner, table_name 
from all_tab_columns
where column_name in ('id1', 'id2');
group by owner, table_name
having count(*) = 2;
```